# central limit theorem for function of random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, central-limit-theorem

Let's say you have $X_1,...,X_n$ observations of a RV X, which is distributed according to some arbitrary prob. function.
Further there is a deterministic function $f(X)=Z$,

$f: X \rightarrow [-1,1]$

Under what conditions is the CLT applicable to the function of a random variable?

Comment: The CLT is not concerned with the mean, but with the distribution (Gaussian). The convergence of the sample mean to the expected value is provided by the LLN (Law of Large Numbrers). Are you confusing CLT and LLN, or are these two different questions?

Comment: sry but I'm not too familiar with that topic. yes, the question is whether the resulting sampling distribution of the mean follows a Gaussian dist.

Answer (score 1):

There is a nice theorem called “The Delta Theorem” which gives conditions for applying the Central Limit Theorem to arbitrary functions of random variables that have a CLT. But that won’t work here unless you have the CLT for the $X_i$s. I’m referencing the book called “Asymptotic Theory of Statistics and Probability” by Anirban DasGupta page 40. It’s a great book that I would recommend referencing if you are interested in applications of the CLT to questions like yours.

Comment: Thx for your answer - I will look it up!

Answer (score 0):

In general, if we have a sequence of iid variables $X_i$, a sufficient condition for applying the CLT (convergence of the normalized sum to a gaussian) is that the variance of $X_i$ is finite. Here, we don't know about that, so we can't apply the CLT to $X_i$. Nevertheless, we want to apply the CLT not to $X_i$ but to $Z_i=f(X_i)$, where $f$ is arbitrary deterministic function (perhaps not continuous, perhaps very ugly) but with bounded codomain. This is the key. This means that the image of the function (and hence the values of $Z_i$) are bounded (included in the interval $[-1,1]$). And this implies that the variance of $Z_i$ is finite. Hence we can apply the CLT to $Z_i$ (and the law of large numbers too).

Comment: thanks, that sounds promising! do you also know good resources to read up on that topic?

Comment: if the "topic" is CLT, any probabilty/statistic texbook discusses it. If the "topic" is this answer, then I've already covered all that it's to say about it.